# Ruby: taking unique subarrays with respect to a specific field

Tags: ruby

Let's say there is an array of arrays of strings:

```
 array = [["John","Apples"],["Tim","Apples"],["Frank","Apples"],
  ["Tom","Pears"],["John","Pears"],["Frank","Oranges"],["Tim","Oranges"]]
```

Now the game is to select any records that are unique on the second value of the Arrays in an easy way, e.g. the result could be:

```
 array2 = [["Frank","Apples"],["Tom","Pears"],["Tim","Oranges"]]
```

Does anyone know if there's a one-liner that does this?

Comment: i like this game. a lot of clever answers were posted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000276) can take a block argument:

```
array.uniq { |e| e[1] }
```

For example:

```
>> array = [["John","Apples"], ["Tim","Apples"], ["Frank","Apples"], ["Tom","Pears"], ["John","Pears"], ["Frank","Oranges"], ["Tim","Oranges"]]
>> array.uniq { |e| e[1] }
=> [["John", "Apples"], ["Tom", "Pears"], ["Frank", "Oranges"]]
```

You'll probably get the first match (rather than the last as in your "could be" output) but I don't think there is any guarantee as to which one will be chosen.

Note that this only works in 1.9, 1.8 doesn't like it so you'll have to work harder in 1.8 but not that much harder:

```
array.inject({ }) { |h,e| h[e[1]] = e[0]; h }.map { |k,v| [ v, k ] }
```

The `inject`/`map` version works the same in 1.8 and 1.9. Also, this one picks the **last** of the duplicated values.

Comment: @nash: Thanks, I'll add a disclaimer. I haven't touched 1.8 for several months.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution that should work in 1.8 and 1.9:

```
array.group_by(&:last).map { |k,v| v.last }
# => [["John", "Pears"], ["Frank", "Apples"], ["Tim", "Oranges"]]
```

Comment: I have a blind-spot for `group_by`, I keep forgetting that it exists.

Comment: @mu is too short: I really like this method, I came in handy so many times already :-)

Comment: For some reason I always assumed "group_by" was an activesupport method, so I never used it when writing plain ruby. Go figure.

Comment: Yeah, `group_by` is nice but I always end up reaching for `inject` instead.

Comment: @Ben Lee: It's been added in 1.8.7 IIRC :-)

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby 1.8:

```
array.map{ |k,v| v }.uniq.map{ |uv| array.select{ |k,v| v == uv }.last }
```

or

```
Hash[*array.map{ |k,v| [v,k] }.flatten].map{ |k,v| [v,k] }
```

*[updated: "mu is too short" gave an excellent answer for Ruby 1.9, and the above answers I gave are good for Ruby 1.8]*

Answer (score 3):

The [facets](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html) gem  implements (amongst a huge amount of other useful methods) a **uniq_by** method:

```
module Enumerable
  def uniq_by #:yield:
    h = {}; inject([]) {|a,x| h[yield(x)] ||= a << x}
  end
end
```